# Tengo que hacer un menú sobre una Pokedex en C y estoy teniendo muchas complicaciones

Tags: c, bucle-for, condiciones, else

necesito terminar una práctica que nos ha mandado mi profesor, se trata de hacer una Pokedex donde metes los datos de un Pokemon (Las veces que quieras) y que al listarlos te salgan todos los que has puesto, aparte de otras cosas más como modificar pokemons, borrarlos, consultar información y dar de baja a los pokemons.

El caso es que me estoy rayando a muerte con los bucles for y con la sentencia if y no se ni donde ponerlas, agradecería que si los resolvéis me lo explicarais ya que tengo un examen de todo esto el viernes que viene.

Os dejo el código aqui:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define cantidadpokemon 151
void aPokemon();
void lcPokemons();
void inicializar();
int espaciolibre();
void Pmenu();

struct tPokemon{
    char nombre[30];
    char tipo[10];
    char visto;
    int salud; 
    int ataque; 
    int defensa;
    int velocidad;
    int atkespecial;
    int dfnespecial;
}pokemon[50];

int main(){
    
    Pmenu();
    inicializar();
    espaciolibre();
    
    return 0;
}

void inicializar(){
    
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<cantidadpokemon;i++){
    pokemon[i].visto==false;
    }

}

void aPokemon(){
        
    int i;
    
    system("cls");
    printf("__________________________________________\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\tDar de alta a un Pokemon\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Nombre del Pokemon: ");
    gets(pokemon[i].nombre);
    scanf("%s",&pokemon[i].nombre);
    printf("Tipo de Pokemon: ");
    gets(pokemon[i].tipo);
    scanf("%s",&pokemon[i].tipo);
    printf("Salud del Pokemon: ");
    scanf("%i",&pokemon[i].salud);
    printf("Ataque del Pokemon: ");
    scanf("%i",&pokemon[i].ataque);
    printf("Defensa del Pokemon: ");
    scanf("%i",&pokemon[i].defensa);
    printf("Velocidad del Pokemon: ");
    scanf("%i",&pokemon[i].velocidad);
    printf("Ataque especial del Pokemon: ");
    scanf("%i",&pokemon[i].atkespecial);
    printf("Defensa especial del Pokemon: ");
    scanf("%i",&pokemon[i].dfnespecial);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\tPokemon dado de alta correctamente, pulse cualquier tecla para continuar\n");
    printf("__________________________________________\n");
    printf("\n");
    getch();
    system("cls");
    
}


int espaciolibre(){
    
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<cantidadpokemon;i++){
    if(pokemon[i].visto==false){
    return i;
}
}
}

void lcPokemons(){
    
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<cantidadpokemon;i++){
    
    system("cls");
    printf("__________________________________________\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\tMostrando todos los Pokemons\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Nombre: %s\n",pokemon[i].nombre);
    printf("Tipo: %s\n",pokemon[i].tipo);
    printf("Salud: %i\n",pokemon[i].salud);
    printf("Ataque: %i\n",pokemon[i].ataque);
    printf("Defensa: %i\n",pokemon[i].defensa);
    printf("Velocidad: %i\n",pokemon[i].velocidad);
    printf("Ataque especial: %i\n",pokemon[i].atkespecial);
    printf("Defensa especial: %i\n",pokemon[i].dfnespecial);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\tPulse cualquier tecla para continuar\n");
    printf("__________________________________________\n");
    printf("\n");
    getch();
    system("cls");


    }
}

void Pmenu(){
        
    int opcion;
    
    do{
        printf("\tLa Pokedex");
        printf("\n__________________________________________");
        printf("\n");
        printf("\n1. Alta de Pokemon");
        printf("\n2. Consulta informacion sobre un Pokemon");
        printf("\n3. Baja de un Pokemon");
        printf("\n4. Modificacion de un Pokemon");
        printf("\n5. Listado de Pokemons");
        printf("\n6. Salir de la Pokedex");
        printf("\n__________________________________________");
        printf("\n");
        printf("\nSelecciona una opcion: ");
        scanf("%i",&opcion);

    switch(opcion){
        case 1:
        aPokemon();
        break;
        case 2:
        /*ciPokemon();*/
        break;
        case 3:
        /*bPokemon();*/
        break;
        case 4:
        /*mPokemon();*/
        break;
        case 5:
        lcPokemons();
        break;
        case 6:
        break;
        default:
        printf("\n Introduce una opcion valida");
        getch();
        break;
        }
    
    }while(opcion != 6); //Se va a repetir hasta que la opcion sea 6
}
/*
void ciPokemon(){
    
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<cantidadpokemon;i++){
        
    system("cls");
    printf("Teclee el identificador del Pokemon");
    scanf("%s",&pokemon[i].nombre);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Informacion sobre el Pokemon");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Nombre: %s\n",(i+1),pokemon[i].nombre);
    printf("Tipo: %s\n",(i+1),pokemon[i].tipo);
    printf("Salud: %i\n",(i+1),pokemon[i].salud);
    printf("Ataque: %i\n",(i+1),pokemon[i].ataque);
    printf("Defensa: %i\n",(i+1),pokemon[i].defensa);
    printf("Velocidad: %i\n",(i+1),pokemon[i].velocidad);
    printf("Ataque especial: %i\n",(i+1),pokemon[i].atkespecial);
    printf("Defensa especial: %i\n",(i+1),pokemon[i].dfnespecial);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\tPulse cualquier tecla para continuar\n");
    printf("__________________________________________\n");
    printf("\n");
    getch();
    system("cls");
    
    }
    
}

void bPokemon(){
    
}

void mPokemon(){
    
}
*/
```

GRACIAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si quieres que los pokemons que introduzcas en la lista de pokemons se guarden de una vez para otra deberías hacer que los guarde en un archivo (Mejor uno .txt porque es más facil de usar). Ademas cuando usas scanf con una variable char[] como "pokemon[i].nombre" o "pokemon[i].tipo" no tienes que poner el signo &.

también cuando vas a escribir todos los pokemons que están registrados no deberías poner en el for un define donde el número de veces que va a repetirse el bucle sino una variable tipo int que tenga dentro el número exacto de pockemons registrdos así solo va a escribir los necesarios. Sino va a escribir el nombre de pokemons que no están definidos.

Otra cosa es que en el void cipokemon que tienes comentada no deberias poner un for que se repita 151 veces sino te va a pedir el nombre de un pokemon para darte su información 151 veces y sospecho que solo quieres que lo haga una XD.

Por último te recomiendo hacer un void pulsa_intro en vez de poner siempre el getch(). El código del void la función pulsa_intro sería este:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void pulsa_intro(char*);

int main()
{
    //Usa la función pulsa_intro(); como si fuese un printf lo único que lo que escribas dentro estará seguido de una pausa.
    pulsa_intro("pulsa una tecla para finalizar");
    return 0;
}

void pulsa_intro(char frase[])
{
    printf("%s",frase);
    getchar();fflush(stdin);
}
```

Esta funcion la tienes que crear copiando el void y cada vez que escribas pulsa_intro("algo"); se escribirá lo que has escrito dentro de las comillas (como un printf) y se hará una pausa despues. Tienes que tener en cuenta que después de la pausa automáticamente se hará un salto de linea.

Comment: si quieres te puedo intentar ayudar más y hasta intentar hacerte alguna funcion y luego explicartela. Pero solo puedo poner comentarios en mis propias respuestas XD.

Comment: Hola Julianix, he conseguido hacerlo gracias al profe y mis compañeros que me ayudaron hace 2 días, gracias igualmente por la respuesta :D

Comment: d nada me alegro de que lo consiguieses :)